# AngularJS: ReferenceError: Angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im creating a simple App with c# WebAPI & AngularJS. Im getting this error in the console, the web its not working.

My Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/Angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/theSoft.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/UsersListController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="theSoft">
        <div ng-controller="UsersListController">
            {{ 1+1 }}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

theSoft.js File:

```
(function () {
    var app = Angular.module("theSoft")
});
```

UserListController.js

```
(function (app) {
    var UsersListController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Guido Caffa";
    };
    app.controller("UsersListController", UsersListController);
}(Angular.module("theSoft")));
```

The error is in line 6, at the UserListController.js

Can anyone helpme ?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `angular` with a small `a`?

Comment: Is it `UserListController.js` or `UsersListController.js`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to add a empty dependency to your module in theSoft.js

```
 var app = angular.module("theSoft",[])
```

also make sure your reference paths are correct,

```
<script src="../../Scripts/Angular.js"></script> // should not this be ../scripts?
<script src="../Scripts/theSoft.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/UsersListController.js"></script>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/XZPj3ZS1a1JmhJ6jVDQs?p=preview)**

Comment: Originally i do it that way, but looking for solve the problem i change it. This dont fix the problem.

Comment: let me create a demo

Comment: @GuidoCaffa it should be angular not Angular

Comment: When i change it, now i  have this error

Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$injector/nomod?p0=theSoft

Comment: You should update your question with whatever changes you have made because it's very unclear what exactly you have changed at this point.

Comment: @Sajeetharan You should add a bit of an explanation so Guido can understand why he needs to add the empty dependency array to the module declaration.  `var app = Angular.module("theSoft")` is a valid line of code if he has declared the module somewhere else so your answer is a bit misleading.

Comment: @BShaps no he has not declared . Don't assume and downvote , ask for clarifications. As i see you do not need to have separate file just to put module. so thats the initial point of declaration

Comment: @Sajeetharan Speaking of assumptions... don't assume who is downvoting you, it wasn't me.  All I was saying is your answer could be improved to educate while answering the question.

Comment: @GuidoCaffa its good if you reply whether the demo solve your issue or not

Comment: @sajeetharan your demo help me solving the problem! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This demo of @Sajeetharan help me solving my problem.
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/XZPj3ZS1a1JmhJ6jVDQs?p=preview

I was using "Angular" instead of "angular". And i was missing a "()" in the end of theSoft.js.

Thanks all!